# A couple of questions based on the order of subgroups and normal subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, normal-subgroups, finitely-generated

Consider the following elements of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$:

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\quad,\quad
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

Let $N$ be the subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ generated by $A$ and $B$.

(i)   **Does $N$ have any elements of order 4?  Justify your answers.**

(ii) **Let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup of $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ generated by $A$.  Is $H$ normal in $N$? Is $H$ normal in $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$? Justify your answers.**

I've calculated that $|A| = 3, |B| = 2 $ and $|AB| = 2$.  Also $|AB| \neq |A||B|$.  Am I meant to use Lagrange's theorem for (i).  If so, how?

As for (ii) I am not sure how to answer this at all.

Thank you

Comment: Note that the subgroup $N$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, answers to (i) and (ii) follows automatically.

Comment: @pisco125 Is there a way to do this without knowing that $N$ is isomorphic to $S_3$?  The question is part of a series which don't include permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By counting elements, you can show that $|N|=6$, so it can't have any elements of order $4$, as $4\nmid 6$. Note that this doesn't involve realizing $N$ as $S_3$.

As you mention, $|A|=3$ and hence $|H|=3$. Since $\frac{6}{3}=2$, $H$ is normal in $N$. Let me know if you need help with the last part about $H\vartriangleleft GL_3(\mathbb{R})$, but you should try for yourself.